# Settings Back Button Isn't Working Using Bellow Code?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, crash

Below link in settings activity cannot go back when back button is pressed.

https://github.com/SadaqaWorks/Word-By-Word-Quran-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sadaqaworks/quranprojects/activity/SettingsActivity.java

Code is given below...

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // handle arrow click here
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)`enter code here`
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

nothing gets work. plz fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use finish() instead of System.exit(0).

And do not override onBackPressed().